# Is it possible to sync only the source codes of xcode project with dropbox?

Tags: xcode, dropbox

Is it possible to sync only the source codes of xcode project with dropbox?
I hope to synchronize only the sources rather than files in build directory under xcode project.

I sit possible?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current versions of Xcode, by default, keep the build directory and other intermediate files in a separate directory under `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.  Assuming you are using a recent Xcode and haven't configured it to save build files in your project directory you should be able to place your project directory in your Dropbox folder.